# How do I install latte-dock in Kubuntu 20.10?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I've been trying to install latte-dock in a VM with Kubuntu 20.10 and nothing seems to work. I cloned the repository and ran `~$ sh install.sh`, and after several fails I got stuck in this error message:

```
$ sh install.sh
install.sh: 12: [: unexpected operator
install.sh: 12: [: unexpected operator
install.sh: 16: [: -a: unexpected operator
install.sh: 22: [: -a: unexpected operator
install.sh: 25: [: -a: unexpected operator
install.sh: 29: [: unexpected operator
install.sh: 32: [: unexpected operator
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find KF5Activities (missing: KF5Activities_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Activities: found neither KF5ActivitiesConfig.cmake nor kf5activities-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5Archive (missing: KF5Archive_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Archive: found neither KF5ArchiveConfig.cmake nor kf5archive-config.cmake 
-- Found KF5CoreAddons: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5CoreAddons/KF5CoreAddonsConfig.cmake (found version "5.74.0") 
-- Found KF5GuiAddons: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5GuiAddons/KF5GuiAddonsConfig.cmake (found version "5.74.0") 
-- Could NOT find KF5Crash (missing: KF5Crash_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Crash: found neither KF5CrashConfig.cmake nor kf5crash-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5DBusAddons (missing: KF5DBusAddons_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5DBusAddons: found neither KF5DBusAddonsConfig.cmake nor kf5dbusaddons-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5Declarative (missing: KF5Declarative_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Declarative: found neither KF5DeclarativeConfig.cmake nor kf5declarative-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5GlobalAccel (missing: KF5GlobalAccel_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5GlobalAccel: found neither KF5GlobalAccelConfig.cmake nor kf5globalaccel-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5Kirigami2 (missing: KF5Kirigami2_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Kirigami2: found neither KF5Kirigami2Config.cmake nor kf5kirigami2-config.cmake 
-- Found Gettext: /usr/bin/msgmerge (found version "0.19.8.1") 
-- Found KF5I18n: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5I18n/KF5I18nConfig.cmake (found version "5.74.0") 
-- Could NOT find KF5IconThemes (missing: KF5IconThemes_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5IconThemes: found neither KF5IconThemesConfig.cmake nor kf5iconthemes-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5KIO (missing: KF5KIO_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5KIO: found neither KF5KIOConfig.cmake nor kf5kio-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5NewStuff (missing: KF5NewStuff_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5NewStuff: found neither KF5NewStuffConfig.cmake nor kf5newstuff-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5Notifications (missing: KF5Notifications_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Notifications: found neither KF5NotificationsConfig.cmake nor kf5notifications-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5Plasma (missing: KF5Plasma_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Plasma: found neither KF5PlasmaConfig.cmake nor kf5plasma-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5PlasmaQuick (missing: KF5PlasmaQuick_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5PlasmaQuick: found neither KF5PlasmaQuickConfig.cmake nor kf5plasmaquick-config.cmake 
-- Could NOT find KF5Wayland (missing: KF5Wayland_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5Wayland: found neither KF5WaylandConfig.cmake nor kf5wayland-config.cmake 
-- Found KF5WindowSystem: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5WindowSystem/KF5WindowSystemConfig.cmake (found version "5.74.0") 
-- Could NOT find KF5XmlGui (missing: KF5XmlGui_DIR)
-- Could NOT find KF5XmlGui: found neither KF5XmlGuiConfig.cmake nor kf5xmlgui-config.cmake 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find KF5 (missing: Activities Archive Crash DBusAddons
  Declarative GlobalAccel Kirigami2 IconThemes KIO NewStuff Notifications
  Plasma PlasmaQuick Wayland XmlGui) (found suitable version "5.74.0",
  minimum required is "5.38.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:94 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I've looked up in several forums but can´t fix the problem. Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++; you're just missing libraries. The required libraries are listed here: https://github.com/KDE/latte-dock#requirements . Note that it specifies that the development libraries are required.

Comment: It's also noted in the repo that latte dock exists as a package already in Ubuntu. Unless you need the bleeding edge, the package is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

For Kubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then do

```
sudo apt install cmake extra-cmake-modules qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5plasma-dev libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5declarative-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev libkf5activities-dev build-essential libxcb-util-dev libkf5wayland-dev git gettext libkf5archive-dev libkf5notifications-dev libxcb-util0-dev libsm-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5newstuff-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev kirigami2-dev
```

Then run

```
./install.sh
```

or conversely you can run

```
sh install.sh
```

The previous commands were to install the dependencies. It's given on the github page:

https://github.com/KDE/latte-dock/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md